# Advice for lots of data clientside in a browser session

Tags: javascript, session, browser, indexeddb

I need some advice.

I'm looking for a way to work with a huge amount of data (800+mb) in the browser. This data should not be persistent. Users upload a csv file which they play with (filter) in the browser before doing anything with it. The columnnames in those csv files can vary wildly.

I was wondering what method to use here. Storing the data in memory in JavaScript variables does not work, as it crashes the page. I've been looking at indexedDB, which gives me the opportunity to keep the data in a database and even gives me filtering options. However this system is actually designed to store persistent data for offline use.
Preferably I would like to delete the database when loading a new file, create a new database with it's own objectstore and fill it with new data. But I found that the database is not deleted as long as I don't refresh the page and I cannot change it.

My questions: is using indexedDB a viable approach for this specific case? If yes, does anyone any pointers how to use it in this case? Are there other possibilities that I have overlooked?

Comment: So how are you removing the data?

Comment: I try to delete the database.